# converting unsigned char * to jbytearray

Tags: c, java-native-interface, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an `unsigned char *` to `jbyteArray` using the following code

```
int callWR(const char *name,unsigned char *ubuf)
{

    jbyteArray bArray=env->NewByteArray(strlen((const char *)ubuf));
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(bArray, 0, strlen((const char *)ubuf), (jbyte *)ubuf);
    jstring tableName= (env)->NewStringUTF(name);       
    int status;     
    status=(int)(env)->CallStaticIntMethod(clsMC,midWRow,tableName,bArray);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(bArray);
    return status;
}
```

Is this the right method to pass a byte array argument through JNI to a java function? is type casting `(jbyte *)ubuf` an efficient way of converting a `unsigned char *` to `jbyte *`? The values that I am getting at the destination seem to be messed up. Help please.

Comment: The casting should work. Not sure about the `strlen()` on the `ubuf` though. Is that byte array really some text that is terminated with a null character (`\0`)? You should rather send in the correct length of the byte array as a parameter. And you don't have to do `DeleteLocalRef` explicitly, it will be done when going out of scope.

Comment: Is there any other way of getting the size then? `sizeof(ubuf)` doesn't give the correct results.

Comment: You'll have to add the length to the function argument list: `int callWR(const char *name, unsigned char *ubuf, size_t ubuf_length)` or similar.

Comment: We could also use [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) and simply call `BytePointer.get()` that does that.